FastifyError: fastify-plugin: fastify-accepts - expected '3.x' fastify version, '4.18.0' is installed
This is happening when i'm trying to upgrade node version to 20
Node.js version
v20.12.2
Operating system
macOS
"dependencies":{
    "@fastify/cookie": "8.2.0",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.2.8",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.4.7",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.4.7",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-fastify": "^9.4.3",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.11",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.4.7",
    "apollo-server-fastify": "^3.13.0",
}



Run npm ls fastify-accepts to spot who is using it. I assume apollo does not work with latest fastify version
